Vite 5.2.0, Vanilla TS, как сделать js файл доступным по ссылке в дев сборке
Всем привет. Есть небольшой проект Vite 5.2.0, Vanilla TS.
Есть вот такой конфиг:
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@src': '/src',
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: 'index.html',
        ph: 'public/ph/index.html',
        mr: 'src/mr/main.ts'
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: ({ name }) => {
          if (name !== 'mr') {
            return 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js'
          }

          return 'mr/main.js';
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

Как вы видите, при сборке я складываю mr: 'src/mr/main.ts' в отдельную папку, без хеша в названии. И это отлично работает.
Вопрос: А можно как-то добиться того же в дев среде? Т.е. мне нужно, чтобы доступ к этому файлу был по ссылке, без хеша. Что-то типа такого http://localhost:5173/mr/main.js (на самом деле путь не принципиален, главное чтобы его можно было открыть).
